# Way to share data between classes in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 kotlin classes and both of them implement the interface `myVariables`. Inside `myVariables` is a variable named `money`. What I am trying to do is have the same variable(and keep its value too) be used inside both classes. Is this a good way to do it?

```
class MainActivity : myVariables, AppCompatActivity() {override val money = 0}
abstract class ShopActivity : myVariables, AppCompatActivity() {override val money = 0}
```

The interface:

```
interface myVariables {
val money: Int
}
```

What is a better way to use the same variable in both of my classes without redefining its value. For example if the variable has gained a value of 5 in the MainActivity class, I want to use the same variable with a value of 5 in the ShopActivity class.

I want the same effect as if this variable was global in the file that is using it, if that makes any sense.

Comment: If you need variable whose value could be access in any class and its value is the same which is in the other class then I think you can use static variable.

Comment: use companion object in kotlin to achieve this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for singleton. And the idiomatic way to create them in Kotlin is to create object (not class), which will hold your variables. Like this:

```
object MyVariables {
  const val string = "foo"
  val pops = 4
}
```

And then you can use it in your class like this:

```
class MyClass {
  fun myMethod() {
    println(MyVariables.string)
  }
}
```

Of course you can use `var`s, not `val`s if you need to change them. But be warned that having a global mutable state is generally a bad idea because it's hard to track over the code, where variable is changed from.

---

Also note that generally it's a bad idea to start names of interfaces from lowercase because it breaks conventions and makes code less readable. It took a couple seconds for me to understand that `myVariables` isn't variable name.